# React: array state length always returns 0 but returns otherwise on useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code :

```
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  const retrieveData = async() => {
    const { ethereum } = window;
    Web3EthContract.setProvider(ethereum);
  
    try {
      console.log("INITIAL LOADING OF GALLERY");
      const smartContractObject = new Web3EthContract(abi, config.CONTRACT_ADDRESS);
      const totalSupply = await smartContractObject.methods.totalSupply().call();
      console.log("index "+data.length); //<--ALWAYS RETURNS 0
      for (let i=1; i<=15;i++) {
        const pngHash = "REDACTED";
        const jsonHash = "REDACTED"
        const owner = await smartContractObject.methods.ownerOf(i+data.length).call();
        const response = await fetch("https://gateway.pinata.cloud/ipfs/"+jsonHash+"/"+(i+data.length)+".json");
        if (response.ok) {
          const json = await response.json();
          console.log("call object");
          const object = {
            background : json.attributes[0] ? json.attributes[0].value : null,
            wings : json.attributes[1].value ? json.attributes[1].value : null,
            body : json.attributes[2].value ? json.attributes[2].value : null,
            mouth : json.attributes[3].value ? json.attributes[3].value : null,
            eyes : json.attributes[4].value ? json.attributes[4].value : null,
            hair : json.attributes[5].value ? json.attributes[5].value : null,
            accessories : json.attributes[6] ? json.attributes[6].value : null,
            ranking : json.ranking,
            race : json.race,
            owner : owner,
            img : "https://ipfs.io/ipfs/"+json.image.substring(7),
            id : i+data.length
          }
          setData(data => [...data, object]);
        } else {
          console.log(response.url);
        }
      } 
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    } 
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data length : " + data.length); //<-- RETURNS UPDATED VALUE
  }, [data]);
```

I am calling the function `retrieveData` every time the user scrolls to the bottom to fetch more data from the blockchain, but it's fetching the same data every time because `data.length` inside the function body always returns 0. However, when I call `data.length` inside the `useEffect` it's giving me the updated value. What's happening here?

Scenario :

1. retrieveData is called initially when component loads so this should populate the data array. I am calling console.log(data.length) on useEffect so I know it's not empty.
2. I scroll at the bottom of the page to trigger listener calling retrieveData again. However, data.length returns 0 here when it was already populated previously.

I am initializing the data and reinvoking the function like so :

```
    useEffect(() => {
        retrieveData();
    
        const onScroll = function () {
          if (window.innerHeight + window.scrollY >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
            retrieveData();
          }
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll)
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', onScroll)

  }, [])
```

Comment: where are you calling retrieveData ??

Comment: Fetching data from `server` is called as a side `effect`. Any side `effect` should be done inside `useEffect()`

Hence you are getting right count inside `useEffect` . Move this function inside `useEffect` as well.

Comment: Since you have put data in the dependency array your retrieveData would fire again when the data changes, so you would get a re-render

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by dependency array. retrieveData is called from a scroll to bottom eventlistener

Comment: It's nice that you tell us how you call `retrieveData`, but could you add the code as well? With the description *“retrieveData is called initially when component loads”* I would expect something like this: `useEffect(() => { retrieveData(); }, []);`. Instead of letting readers guess your code, it's probably better to just supply the relevant code in the question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly how I call it. I am currently away, will edit later.

Comment: What about the second invocation? How is `retrieveData` attached to a scroll event? Are you by any chance using `useEffect(() => { window.addEventListener("scroll", retrieveData ); return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", retrieveData); }, []);`?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.